# MongoDB data aggregation assistance

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have 'customers' collection with the following document:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Customer Name',
  projects: [
    {
      id: 1000,
      name: 'Project 1',
      description: 'Project description',
      instances: [10, 20],
    },
    {
      id: 2000,
      name: 'Project 2',
      description: 'Project description',
      instances: [30, 40, 10],
    }
  ]
}
```

I have another collection 'instances' which looks like the following:

```
[
  {
    id: 10,
    operatingSystem: 'Microsoft Windows 2012R2',
    version: '3.1.5',
    product: {
      id: 100,
      name: 'Product 1',
      vendor: 'Vendor A',
    },
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    operatingSystem: 'Microsoft Windows 2016',
    version: '4.1.0',
    product: {
      id: 200,
      name: 'Product 5',
      vendor: 'Vendor B',
    },
  },
  {
    id: 30,
    operatingSystem: 'Microsoft Windows 2019',
    version: '3.0',
    product: {
      id: 300,
      name: 'Product 2',
      vendor: 'Vendor A',
    },
  },
  {
    id: 40,
    operatingSystem: 'Linux',
    version: '1.0',
    product: {
      id: 100,
      name: 'Product 1',
      vendor: 'Vendor A',
    }
  }
]
```

I'm trying to use the aggregation framework to make the results look like the following:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Customer Name',
  projects: [
    {
      id: 1000,
      name: 'Project 1',
      description: 'Project description',
      products: [
        {
          id: 100,
          name: 'Product 1',
          vendor: 'Vendor A',
          instances: [
            {
              id: 10,
              operatingSystem: 'Microsoft Windows 2012R2',
              version: '3.1.5',
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: 200,
          name: 'Product 5',
          vendor: 'Vendor B',
          instances: [
            {
              id: 20,
              operatingSystem: 'Microsoft Windows 2016',
              version: '4.1.0',
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2000,
      name: 'Project 2',
      description: 'Project description',
      products: [
        {
          id: 300,
          name: 'Product 2',
          vendor: 'Vendor A',
          instances: {
            id: 30,
            operatingSystem: 'Microsoft Windows 2019',
            version: '3.0',
          },
        },
        {
          id: 100,
          name: 'Product 1',
          vendor: 'Vendor A',
          instances: [
            {
              id: 40,
              operatingSystem: 'Linux',
              version: '1.0',
            },
            {
              id: 10,
              operatingSystem: 'Microsoft Windows 2012R2',
              version: '3.1.5',
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The current pipeline I managed to build is:

```
[{$match: {
  _id: 1
}}, {$unwind: {
  path: "$projects"
}
}, {$lookup: {
  from: 'instances',
  localField: 'projects.instances',
  foreignField: '_id',
  as: 'projects.instances'
}}, {$group: {
  _id: "$projects.instances.product",
  test: { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
}}, {$unwind: {
  path: "$_id"
}}, {$unwind: {
  path: "$test"
}}, {$project: {
  _id: "$test._id",
  name: "$test.name",
  description: "$test.description",
  projects: {
    _id: "$test.projects._id",
    name: "$test.projects.name",
    description: "$test.projects.description",
    products: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      name: "$_id.name",
      vendor: "$_id.vendor",
      instances: "$test.projects.instances",
    }
  }
}}, {$group: {
  _id: "$_id",
  name: {"$first": "$name"},
  projects: {
    "$push": "$projects"
  }
}}]
```

But I'm getting duplicates in the 'projects' array (if I'm having the same project with a different product, it will show twice instead of having a single project with 2 products in the products array

Will appreciate your help with finding the right pipeline stages to manipulate my results are expected

Comment: Would you mind explaining your current pipeline? it does not seem to match with the data sample you provided.

Comment: I actually removed some fields from the examples I published here to not confuse and forgot to remove those from the pipeline I've tried. I'm updating the question with the correct pipeline. Thank you for helping!

Comment: @TomSlabbaert done, I have updated the question with the correct values. as again, thank you for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't follow your pipeline as it was easier for me to just rewrite it from scratch but here's how I would do it, the obvious data structure manipulation concepts remain the same:

```
db.customers.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$projects"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "instances",
      let: {
        instances: "$projects.instances"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $setIsSubset: [
                [
                  "$id"
                ],
                "$$instances"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "projects.instances"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$projects.instances"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        id: "$_id",
        project: "$projects.name",
        product: "$projects.instances.product.id"
      },
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      description: {
        $first: "$projects.description"
      },
      product: {
        $first: "$projects.instances.product"
      },
      instances: {
        $push: {
          id: "$projects.instances.id",
          operatingSystem: "$projects.instances.operatingSystem",
          version: "$projects.instances.version",
          
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        id: "$_id.id",
        project: "$_id.project"
      },
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      description: {
        $first: "$description"
      },
      products: {
        $push: {
          $mergeObjects: [
            "$product",
            {
              instances: "$instances"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.id",
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      projects: {
        $push: {
          name: "$project_name",
          description: "$description",
          products: "$products"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iJDOvycsCnk)

Comment: After deeply testing the solution I found 2 issues: 1) if I have a product with a single instance, it's result an object instead of an array with a single item (I think I fixed it by replacing the '$arrayElemAt' with just '$instances' on the seconds '$group').
Unfortunately, I was not able to resolve the second issue:
The products are associated with the wrong projects. It's happened on the first '$group' when '$push' the instances, it somehow push the wrong products to the wrong projects... Is there a way I can share with you the complete project so you can help me resolve it please?

Comment: 1. in the output you required the instances were an object and not an array in the case of 1 instance. In the future be very specified and accurate what output you want as even a minor difference can have a ripple effect on the code. regarding point 2 i edited my answer to fix the issue. I just forgot to add the project name to the first group.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, next time I will triple check myself and put my attention to the smallest details. It's now working as expected. Thank you very much for spending your time to help and provide this elegant solution!